# Multiple instances on a lanes BPMN

Tags: bpmn

I have seen some BPMN models that have a "multiple instance" attached to the pool (3 vertical lines on the bottom of the pool). I think this represents that multiple persons are executing all those tasks on paralell.

My question is if it is valid to do that, but on a lane. If it is possible to attach a "multiple instance" sign on a single lane on a model to represent that multiple persons execute this tasks.

(I am currently grading some tests and I came up with this question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading from the [BPMN2.0 standard](http://www.bpmn.org/) it is allowed to add the multi instances attribute to a pool or lane.

https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF Chapter
9.4 – PartnerRole attributes, Page 147

> Participant Multiplicity
>
> ParticipantMultiplicity is used to define the multiplicity of a Participant.
> For example, a manufacturer can request a quote from multiple suppliers in a Collaboration.

Comment: Thank you so much Simulant! I wasn't aware of the existence of that book.

Comment: Multiplicity still seems to refer to pools rather than lanes. The most recent spec is 2.0.2, where Section 9.3 "Pool and Participant" says on page 111: "A Pool is the graphical representation of a Participant in a Collaboration." In the same section, you have `ParticipantMultiplicity` mentioned on pages 115 and 116 with no reference to lanes. Then, Section 9.3.2 says "A Lane is a sub-partition within a Process (often within a Pool)" with no hint that a lane could have multiple instances within the pool. See [https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN](https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN)