# BPMN - For loop inside for loop with different lines

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I try to model simple process:

1. Chairman send order to all managers
2. Each of managers, in parallel, recive it and base on it they send order to workers
3. Each of them, in parallel, recive it and the process end

The problem is that parallel (for loop) action inside another paraller action. Every manager recive order and then send orders without waiting for other managers, then every of workers recive it.
I throught that paraller sub-process for these three task (recive, send, revice) with last task also paraller will be enough, but then I read that sub-process can't have lines inside so I they can't have both managers and workers inside:

> An embedded subprocess can occur only within a parent process to which it belongs. An embedded subprocess cannot contain pools and lanes, but it can be placed within the pool or the lane of the parent process.

So now I don't know how should I model it. I didn't find any solution.

I attach my work, that I know is wrong, to visualize the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/54wy6.png

Answer (score 0):

**First option**

BPMN allows multiple-instance pools which must have three vertical lines as a marker at the bottom (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952461/multiple-instances-on-a-lanes-bpmn)).

From [BPMN definition document](https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF) (chapter 9.2):

> BPMN specifies a marker for Pools: a multi-instance marker May be displayed for a Pool (see Figure 9.6). The marker is used if the Participant defined for the Pool is a multi-instanceParticipant. [...]
>
> - The marker for a Pool that is a multi-instance MUST be a set of three vertical lines in parallel.
> - The marker, if used, MUST be centered at the bottom of the shape.

---

**Second option:**

Describe just a single instance of the process (i.e. from one worker's point of view) with one chairman, one manager, one worker in your process diagram and describe the [multiplicities](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html) in a complementary diagram (e.g. UML object diagram) like this:

[image: multiplicities example]