# Petri Net to BPMN

Tags: bpmn

I've got a problem with how to transform Petri Diagram to BPMN. I don't know how to "simulate" tokens, and the situation when the flow goes back to the start.

[image: petri diagram]

Can anyone show me how the correct BPMN should look? :)

Answer (score 1):

I basically see the three BPNM tasks *Record proposal*, *Grant a loan*, and *Refuse and notify* here. The *Consideration* place is actually a choice and would become a BPNM gateway.

You example seems to involve two actors: one making proposals and another one deciding whether to accept or refuse a proposal. This should be modeled by showing a separate pool for each actor.

If there are multiple instances that make the proposals, the [multi instances attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952461/multiple-instances-on-a-lanes-bpmn) can be used on the pool.
If it is important that you can process exactly three proposals, I would include this in the far right condition (gateway) or as a text annotation.

So my idea of a BPMN diagram is this:

[image]

But it really depends on what aspects of the process you want to show in the model.